# Building proper class and passing a class method

Tags: ruby, class

```
class Health 

  def initialize()
    @hydration=hydration
  end

  def hydration

    puts"Amount of Water drunk(in oz):"
    x=gets.chomp    
    if #{x}>=20
            puts"Good job! keep on it"
    elsif #{x} >=(10...20)  
      puts"Could do better"
    else 
      puts"Not healthy. Go get hydration"
    end
  end

  drinks=Health.new()
  puts drinks.hydration
end
```

I am new to ruby and what i'm trying to achieve is to be prompted. i'm getting the "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end" on the puts drinks.hydration

Comment: @maringan: Please don't correct code errors in questions. Fixing broken code formatting is great and everybody will appreciate it, but you want to make sure you don't change the code itself (such as moving lines around) since that's what the question is about.

Comment: yes, you have right, sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you should get any syntax error with your current code. In order to make it working you need to remove the comments in if statements. Also the initialize statement is redundant as you are making explicit call to the method hydration in puts drinks.hydration.

```
class Health
  def hydration

    puts "Amount of Water drunk(in oz):"
    x=gets.chomp.to_i
    if x>=20
      puts "Good job! keep on it"
    elsif (10...20).include? x
      puts "Could do better"
    else
      puts "Not healthy. Go get hydration"
    end
  end
end
drinks=Health.new()
puts drinks.hydration
```

Comment: Thank you. i was having so much trouble with this.